# Sequelize connection error is failing with the message - Net.Connect is not a function

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to use Sequelize (4.32.1) in one of my app. However, I am getting the following error

[image]

I am using the code as follows

**Connection.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const Connection = new Sequelize('mysql://gjanjua@10.30.24.35:3306/executions');



module.exports = {
    Connection
}
```

**Executions.js**

```
const { Connection } = require('./Connection');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const Executions = Connection.define('executions', {
    controller_ip: Sequelize.STRING,
    number_of_runners: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    overall_result: Sequelize.STRING,
    comments: Sequelize.STRING,
    plan_name: Sequelize.STRING,
    wss_version: Sequelize.STRING,
    build_type: Sequelize.STRING,
    build_flavour: Sequelize.STRING,
    number_erred: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    number_passed: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    number_failed: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    number_warnings: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    number_timeouts: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    number_skipped: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    total_tests: Sequelize.INTEGER,

    started_timestamp : {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue : Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    },
    scheduled_timestamp: {
        type:Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue : Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    },
    completed_timestamp: {
        type:Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue : Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    }
}, { freezeTableName: true, timestamps: false })

module.exports = {
    Executions
}
```

and I am trying to use it as follows

```
const {Executions} = require( '../db/Executions');

Executions.all().then(function(vm) {
    this.executions = vm;
    console.log({vm});
}.bind(this)).catch(function(err) {
    if(err.name == "SequelizeConnectionError") {
        console.error({err})
        alert("There was an error while connecting to the database. Please make sure you have a valid connection.")
    } else {
        throw err
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    alert(err.original.message);
});
```

I can connect to the database using the credentials using a Database Management system but I am unable to get this working.

Can you please help me out with this ?

Thanks

Comment: That’s quite the stack trace!

Comment: Please let me know if you would like me to truncate it !

Comment: It might be helpful if you could look through it and see if anything stands out to you, then delete the rest. It will always be in the edit history of the post.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?